# play raw audio data received through a stream

Tags: ios, audio, nsdata, playback, rtmp

I am developing an audio and video streaming application using an RTMP connection library. This particular library gives the audio data with the type NSData. I am encountering a problem
while playing the audio data. Which method can be appropriate to play data in such a form ?

Comment: What you got as error? show some error log with corresponding code?

Comment: Show some code where you are stuck?

Comment: my question is how can I play the data received? for eg. using AudioQueues or Mvmovieplayer? what can I use to play my raw audio data received through a stream ?